# Excel macro pivot table refresh sets Err Number to 40040 but succeeds - why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I wrote that I use to refresh some pivot tables. In case the worksheet or pivot table doesn't exist, I test Err.Number to be non-zero but it always returns as 40040 but succeeds anyway without any warnings (other than my own). I work around it by just testing that Err.Number is not 0 or 40040 but I'd like to know why it returns 40040 when there is no error happening and everything works. When I record Excel and insert a line after the refresh indicating the error number it shows the same.

I also had to reset the error number after the first refresh otherwise I would sometimes get error 1004 even though it also succeeds in running.

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Pivots 1o").PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotCache.Refresh
If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 40040 Then Call MsgBox("Warning: couldn't refresh pivots on 'Pivots 1o' worksheet", vbCritical, "handlePivot()")
Err.Number = 0  ' During testing I forced the above error warning and it gave me the below error warning too (error 1004). Setting to 0 here seems to avoid this for some reason.

Worksheets("Pivots 2o").PivotTables("Pivot2").PivotCache.Refresh
If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 40040 Then Call MsgBox("Warning: couldn't refresh pivots on 'Pivots 2o' worksheet", vbCritical, "handlePivot()")
On Error GoTo 0
```

Would anyone know why these errors that are only detected if I explicitly test for them are happening?

Comment: What's the error message? You can comment out `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: There is no error message when removing `On Error Resume Next`. That is what I mean that these errors are only detected when I explicitly test for them.

Comment: I suggest to reset errors by `Err.Clear` to ensure, that they are not resulting from previous code.

Comment: Related: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1750816

Comment: Thanks. Am using `Err.Clear` now. Perhaps it is some kind of Excel bug.